# Understanding the definition of convexity in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, definition

I'm taking a course in real analysis.
The formal definition of convexity is given as follows:

The subset $A \subset \mathbb R^k$ is convex if for all $x,y \in A$ if the whole line section between $x$ and $y$ also lies in $A$. 
The formal definition

$$\forall x,y \in A, \lambda \in (0,1) : \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$$

I have no familiarity with convexity other than see some drawing of the concept in a $\mathbb R^2$ plane. I'm trying to figure out why the formal definition looks like that.

I have no understanding of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y\in\mathbb R^k$, then$$\{\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\mid\lambda\in[0,1]\}$$is the line segment joining $x$ to $y$. Therefore, that definition simpliy means “if $x,y\in A$, then the line segment joining them is contained in $A$”.

Comment: Oh, okay. This was actually what I was thinking, but I could (still can) not figure out have the line segment is parameterised.

Comment: Note that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ is $y$ when $\lambda=0$ and $x$ when $\lambda=1$. Does this help?

Comment: It actually makes some things much clear than the representation in my textbook.  But to be honest I still do not know how the line segment is parameterised. Is the line segment parameterised from $y$ to $x$, right?

Comment: Yes. Another way of seeing it is:$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y=y+\lambda(x-y).$$So, you add to $y$ the vector that goes from $y$ to $x$ times a scalar $\lambda\in[0,1]$. It is clear that you get $y$ if $\lambda=0$ and that you get $x$ if $\lambda=1$.

Comment: Amazing explanation. I finally understand this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One last question. Could $A$ be an improper subset, for example  $A=\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: Yes, no problem abou that.